# Boost parralel messaging performance (TPL / Async)

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, task

I have a performance optimization problem that has been bothering me for some time. I have tried to squeeze more performance from it without much success.

The system (simplified) is as follows:

1)  Requests come in over an HTTP Post (I need to respond synchronously / inline)

2)  I process the request, and return a response (all XML)

3)  If I do not have a result ready within 15 seconds, I respond with a 'server busy, try later' type message.

As the central message processing mechanism I have used a Task based approach to queue, start and wait for messages (max of 15 seconds)

When a message is processed almost instantaneously, the throughput (requests per second) is quite good (1000/s). However, when message processing is delayed by 200ms, this degrades rather badly to 40/s

A few snippets:

```
    public void AddMessage()
    {
         Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        return worker.ProcessMessage();
                    };
    }

    public MessageResponse GetResult()
            {
                task.Task.Wait(15 * 1000);

                switch (task.Status)
                {
                    case TaskStatus.Running:
                            message = "Your request is taking longer than usual"
                       break;
                    case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
                            message = (MessageResponse)task.Result;
                        break;
                }
       return message;
    }
```

Note:

Task creation options None / Longrunning / PreferFairness has no impact. When running the visual studio performance analyser, I can visually see Longrunning creating a new thread for each request (expected), and None using a limited number (underlying threadpool) to service the requests.

Looking at both ANTS performance profiler and Visual studio Performance analyzer, there are no concurrency issues around contention and no other obvious areas where time is being wasted (either cpu time or wall clock time)

What is clear from the visualized results is that in a situation where say 1000 requests are queued, 90% of the program time is spent on thread servicing and context switching

(obviously very expensive). My conclusion is that waiting on the result (over multiple requests) is very costly.

If i doing this on a web page or WPF form I could make it completely asyncronous, however I dont have this option.

Is there any where I can alter the message processing mechanism to optimize concurrency better? I am open to anything really , would even explore async / await if it would benefit.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You mention that you're not doing this in a web page or WPF form - where is it happening?

Comment: Your case statement misses `break`s.

Comment: Nice catch - it helps if you show us the real code (this won't compile)

Comment: If you're creating a task each time a thread comes in, this is going to be inefficient. Have you considered a message pump, such that you queue the operations and then have TPL pull a chunk and perform processing on that? Then you only ever have a few threads running at once if you are blocking, avoiding the thread servicing problem. If you don't block, each chunk of threads will process quickly and pull new chunks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that you're seeing performance degradation due to the use of two threads per request.

Since you mention you're open to `async`/`await`, I would attempt something like this:

```
public async Task<MessageResponse> GetResult(Message message)
{
  var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
  try
  {
    return await Task.Run(() => worker.ProcessMessage(message, cts.Token));
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    return "Your request is taking longer than usual";
  }
}
```

You'd also have to modify `ProcessMessage` to periodically call `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`. Also, if your message processing is I/O-bound rather than CPU-bound, you should change `ProcessMessage` to be `async`.

Comment: Stephen - Thanks for the async / await recommendation. I have tried to implement it as you suggested, and from what I can see the message processing is now done all asynchronously. However it hasn't seemed to provide any better performance. I ultimately still have to do a   [return GetResult(message).Result] which still blocks and waits the length of the message processing time.

Comment: Then you're still using two threads per request. What host are you using?

Comment: Hosted in IIS - via HTTP Post. Request comes in, have to block until I receive something I can give back to the caller.

Comment: Research your framework (MVC/WebAPI/etc) to see if it can handle `async` responses.

Comment: Thanks, looking into using async Http handler to solve this. Some initial results arent scaling as I had hoped, but I would perhaps need to delve a bit deeper to see if my implementation is correct.

Comment: So finally solved the problem by using a custom .axd Async HTTP handler, coupled with the suggested async approach above. The really strange thing is that it would work fine in IIS8 express, but did not work in desktop IIS versions (7.5). Only server 7.5. No idea why this was.